# Using a while loop

Tags: php

Im trying to make a while loop that tells me when I've rolled a 6 on a die.  Can you help me on the below is not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your own do-while</title>
        <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $roll = 1

    while ($roll != 6);
    {
        $roll = rand(0,6);
        echo "Rolled a ". $roll . "<br>"; 

    }
    echo "You finally rolled a ". $roll;

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a spurious semi-colon after the while loop and are missing a semi-colon after `$roll=1`

Comment: can you give a result of this code ?

Comment: Is this a 7-sided die? Your code is for a die with faces 0 to 6, not 1 to 6.

Answer (score 1):

With the changes made as noted in the comments this appears to work ok.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your own do-while</title>
        <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

    $roll = 1;

    do {
        $roll = rand(1,6);/* Dice are numbered from 1-6, not 0-6! */
        echo "Rolled a ". $roll . "<br>"; 

    } while ( $roll !== 6 );
    echo "You finally rolled a ". $roll;

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not seem to work:

    <?php
    $roll = 1;

    while ($roll != 6)
    {
        $roll = rand(0,6);
        echo "Rolled a ". $roll . "<br>"; 
    }
    echo "You finally rolled a ". $roll;
    ?>

Comment: @SamPhilips It is legit PHP and works fine. It does what you asked for. You can write without a do-while-loop but that's not the point.

Comment: @SamPhilips It works: http://ideone.com/OHLh0V

Answer (score -1):

```
     {
    $roll = rand(0,6);
    echo "Rolled a ". $roll . "<br>";
    $roll++;

}
```

You should add '$roll++' in while

Comment: why should the @OP increment by one the random value?